# JavaFX for iphone ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, javafx, for-loop

i need to know that can JavaFX application run into IPHONE IPAD?
Is there any JavaFX runtime in these device.

Comment: If you want people to answer your questions, you should mark your questions as answered appropriately.  Otherwise people will probably stop answering your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[No it can't.](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/robogeek/archive/2010/02/03/ipad-flash-kerfluffle-applets-and-javafx)  The ipad cannot run JavaFX, Flash, Silverlight, or Java Applets.  Apple has explicitly not allowed these.  The basic options are HTML5/Javascript apps on the web or native apps which run on your phone.  If you want to run Java on an ipad, the closest you can come is [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) which you can use to write a web app and host on a server.  It cannot be installed on the phone as a native app (except perhaps through PhoneGap).  The ipad user would then access your app through the web browser.

If you are serious about writing apps for a phone in Java, you should consider [Android](http://www.android.com/).  You can write Android apps in Java, though again not in JavaFX.

**[EDIT]**

Apparently this has changed since I first answered this question as seen [in this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860931/is-it-possible-to-run-javafx-applications-on-iphone-android-win8-mobile)  It is now possible to run JavaFX on ios.

Comment: Not sure this is really relevant to the question, but for anyones information, JavaFX /should/ work on windows mobile. I tried it and failed because of the use of 3rd party libraries that required classes not in "Windows Mobile Java Edition". Damn ms for the toomanyeth time!

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually, it **can**.

You can use [JavaFXPorts](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/javafxports/) or somethings else. 
But, JavaFXPorts doesn't provide full support of JavaFX.

Answer (score 1):

It can't right now. A couple of days ago, however, at the JavaOne conference, a demo of a JavaFX app running on an iPad was made.

From [this article](http://www.infoworld.com/d/application-development/oracle-shows-javafx-ios-and-android-174996):

> Java has been barred from Apple's iOS devices, thanks to Apple's official policy not allowing third-party technologies, such as Flash Player or Java, on the units.
>   But a brief demonstration showed a JavaFX game running on an iPad.
>   This effort effectively puts Java on iOS but is still in a
>   developmental mode. "We want to hear from the community. If this is
>   something you want to see, we're happy to make it a priority," said
>   Nandini Ramani, vice president of development in the Oracle Fusion
>   Middleware Group.