# Build JavaFX app in Android using Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, javafx, javafx-8, build.gradle

I have created a JavaFX application using Javafx 2.2 and its running perfect in desktop. How to run javafx application in mobile platform especially in android mobile phone.

Comment: but in below URL, they saying that it can be excecute in android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860931/is-it-possible-to-run-javafx-applications-on-iphone-android-win8-mobile

Comment: ok.. let me know if you get any idea on tha. i tried using gradle to generate an apk file, but its failed

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [JavaFXPorts](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/javafxports/) project. Since you are already using Gradle, the `jfxmobile-plugin` will take care of porting your JavaFX code to other platforms like Android and iOS, as well as desktop.

To get you started, Gluon provides a [plugin](http://gluonhq.com/products/tools/) for several IDEs, helping you creating a simple project, where you can add your source code. Different tasks will take care of building the project, running it on desktop or deploying it to mobile platforms. Have a look at this [post](http://gluonhq.com/the-new-gluon-plugin-for-intellij-idea) for instance.

Review the list of [prerequisites](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_prerequisites) before getting started (like intalling Android SDK)