# how to deploy java fx application in android platform

Tags: android, deployment, javafx-2

I have a JavaFX2 application, is possible the deployment for android platform? it's a very simple application, I didnt use external libraries, stranges libraries, just the bassic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. JavaFX ported to many popular platforms. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20869409/2413972) you can find the list.

[Or go directly to ports website](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_android)