# Is it possible to run JavaFX desktop application in Android mobiles without any changes?

Tags: java, javafx

I am just new to the JavaFX application, can anyone tell me that JavaFX desktop application can be run in Android mobiles? Or we need any changes to the desktop application to run in Android mobiles? If yes how to do it? Please guide me to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860931/is-it-possible-to-run-javafx-applications-on-iphone-android-win8-mobile

Answer (score 0):

This is the page you want to start with:
http://gluonhq.com/open-source/javafxports/

In practice however you will have to make some adjustments because a mobile application normally simply has different requirements than a desktop app. For example you might want to use GPS or a camera which is not so likely for a desktop app. The important point however is that you can share a large part of your code base and you only have to learn one framework.